# ObjectStateEntry does not update until I check db.Entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I am using an API based implementation for Entity Framework; EF objects are cast to DTO (Data Transfer Objects) before being sent for consumption to the client.

On the way back in, I am changing back from DTOs to my entity types; I am having issues with the concurrency check on DELETE/UPDATE calls. I am using EF 6 and webAPI 2.

What is happening is that, after loading an object from the database, I must make a call to db.Entry(object) before the Object State Entry actually changes to 'Modified'.

Code:

```
    [Route("")]
    [HttpDelete]
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteAssetType(long id, DateTimeOffset modifyDate)
    {
        try
        {
            AssetType assetType = await db.AssetTypes.FindAsync(id);
            if (assetType == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            //Set modifyDate to match what API received and then mark record for deletion
            ObjectStateEntry ose = ((IObjectContextAdapter) db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(assetType);
            assetType.ModifyDate = modifyDate;
            ose.AcceptChanges();
            db.AssetTypes.Remove(assetType);

            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                //TODO Handle Concurrency Exception Specifically (if needed)
                throw;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO Add Error Handling Code
            throw;
        }

        //return Ok(assetType);
        return Ok();
    }
```

... and the problem is that, after the call assetType.ModifyDate = modifyDate (this is my concurrency pattern), if I look at ose.State, it's "Unchanged". If, however, via the debugger, I look at db.Entry(assetType), and THEN look at ose, at that point ose will correctly say "Modified".

The core problem is that the call to ose.AcceptChanges() does nothing, because it sees the object as Unmodified.

I can fix this by just calling db.Entry(assetType) and doing literally NOTHING with the resulting object, and from that point on it works flawlessly, but this seems to suggest I'm doing something wrong somewhere else, as FindAsync claims it attaches the entity to the context, and thus I should NOT have to call .Entry before asking for the state.

As an extended example of what I mean, if I do the following:

```
...
assetType.ModifyDate = modifyDate;
var state = db.Entry(assetType).State;  /* ADDED THIS LINE */
ose.AcceptChanges();
....
```

... then the call to ose.AcceptChanges() does exactly what I expect. My question/issue is WHY do I have to call db.Entry(assetType) in order for the system to see the object as changed? Is it not already attached to the context via the FindAsync earlier, and should it not automatically pick up the change to modifyDate? If it matters, this is db-first with an edmx file, not code first.

EDIT: Modified to include full code for Delete API function.

EDIT 2: Clarified What I'm asking for / what makes this work / what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AssetType assetType = await db.AssetTypes.FindAsync(id); //get object from db
assetType.ModifyDate = modifyDate; //modify it
var state = db.Entry(assetType).State; //get current state, which should be Modified
var updatedRecords = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The problem seems to be that the state you obtained was before any change was made to the entity.
By the way, method Remove (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679171(v=vs.113).aspx) marks an entity as deleted, so I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: This works in the sense that state does say "Modified". The problem I'm struggling with, though, is that i DO mean Remove; what I want to do is delete the object from the database IF the modify-date field in the database matches what the API received.

I'll modify my question to make it a bit clearer - the issue I'm having is that I seem to HAVE to call db.Entry(assetType), regardless of what I do with the result of the call, before the state actually correctly set's itself to Modified.